# Python cannot print the client IP or client hostname

Tags: python, centos, samba

How can I print the IP or hostname of the client pc who delete a file in my shared folder?This code is working but it only print my own IP and Hostname not the other pc that delete a file inside my shared folder.
Im using **Centos 6.3**.I use **Samba** to share my folder.I use **Python 2.7** and **PYinotify** script.

This is my code

```
import pyinotify

wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()

mask = pyinotify.IN_DELETE | pyinotify.IN_CREATE

class EventHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):

    def process_IN_CREATE(self, event): 
    print "",now.strftime("%b-%d-%Y @ %I:%M %p"),"  "   ,socket.gethostname()," ","Create ","  ",event.name,"  ",event.path

    def process_IN_DELETE(self, event):
    print "",now.strftime("%b-%d-%Y @ %I:%M %p"),"  "    ,socket.gethostname()," ","Shift+Del","",event.name," ",event.path

handler = EventHandler()

notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, handler)

wdd = wm.add_watch('/echoshare', mask, rec=True)

auto_add = '/echoshare'

notifier.loop()
```

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific programming questions - what problem are you having in implementing this? Please post your current code and any errors or unexpected output you get.

Comment: Im a newbie her I cant post my codes.The only problem is how can i get the IP address or hostname of a computer that accessing my file? Im using pyinotify. I will post my script when I learned how to edit here.

Comment: Thank you for posting your current code, now you need to tell us what is going wrong - do you get an error? Does it not work? If so, how does it not work? What output do you get that you do not expect?

Comment: Actually its working..but the problem is the script on log its own IP or hostname NOT the other computer who delete on the shared folder. Thank you for the reply sir.

Comment: Is this your whole code? where are `domainname` and `domainname4` defined?

Comment: I cannot post the whole codes because I dont know how to edit here.Im only a noob.But im try please wait and help me guys this is my task on my work.thanks

Comment: You have already edited the post twice.

Comment: Sorry sir I dont know the rules here. the original code is located at my profile. Thanks

Comment: Your profile isn't really the best place to put code. Can you edit your question and put the code there?

Comment: Thank for replying in my Question. This is the scenario. I have two computers connected on a network.PC1 is the server where I shared the folder /echoshare.Then PC2 delete a folder inside /echoshare.The python script print in the Terminal the TIME/DATE/FILENAME/USER/HOSTNAME but the USER and HOSTNAME that it prints was its own USER and HOSTNAME NOT the PC2. Can you get the logic?

Comment: Thank You Mr. Kevin for editing! :)

Comment: Is this your real code? Because you normally can't call `socket.gethostbyname` with zero arguments.

Comment: It was socket.gethostname() sorry again sir Kevin.Im trying all socket codes but it always print my own IP.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand what (py)inotify is.
It is a way to monitor filesystem events and you will get information about operations done by samba server on **local** filesystem.

If you take a look on [inotify documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) you will notice that inotify_event structure does not carry any information about user performing the operations.

I guess a simplest solution to you problem would be to enable [event logging](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Event_Logging) on your samba server and parse generated events for information you want

Comment: +1, I came to the same conclusion. The OP may also find [this link](http://moiristo.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/samba-logging-user-activity/) useful. It describes using a `full_audit` module to log things such as username, IP, etc whenever a user creates/renames/deletes a file. I have no Samba experience but I suspect it may be helpful.

Comment: I know that event logging using the edited smb.conf but the problem is when you delete a 500kb file,it will log 10 times because its divided in 50kb/log..This one problem why my supervisor drop this task

Comment: @Kevin it think it is exactly what OP wants +1 it is syslog based which gives a chance to log events form several servers

Comment: I use this 2 logging events but has 1 problem.... 1st. SMB.conf = logs so many times if you delete a file more than 50kb 100kb = 2 log but same log. 2nd. PYinotify = cannot log the user performing task. If you can give me any application that can log the user who delete a file in a shared folder that can make me happy